# ReactJS: Firebase Sort date as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the DateFrom field in firebase being stored as a string "dd/mm/YY" (ie 20/05/2022)

When I try to sort this via:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore() //access firestore
      .collection("trips")
      .where("User", "==", user1)
      .orderBy("DateFrom", "asc")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const listItemsTrips = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }));
        setItems(listItemsTrips);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
  return items;
```

it returns for the most part the correct results, but anything assigned to say 21/05/2023 will still appear after the 20/05/2022 date. How do I sort this string field by date? (through firebase console, doing a sort on the DateFrom field also shows in this order)

It looks to just be sorting by day & month and ignoring the year value?

Comment: I think the problem is with the string datatype of the field. Try to store it as a date instead of string, it would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the date in firebase as timestamp. Example:

```
yourRef
  .collection('you_colletcyion')
  .add({DateFrom: firebase.Timestamp.now()})
```

So

```
const unsubscribe = firebase
  .firestore() //access firestore
  .collection("trips")
  .where("User", "==", user1)
  .orderBy("DateFrom", "asc")
```

Then you can show the date by formatting it. Example with `moment.js`:

```
moment(user.DateFrom).locale('pt-br').format('LLL')
```

Comment: Even better would be to use Firestore's native `Timestamp` type: `DateFrom: Timestamp.now()`

Comment: I ended up using: DateFrom: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(datefrom)) ... I show these items within a map using item.DateFrom ... but doing so returns the error "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." ... I did try DateFrom: item.DateFrom.toDate() ... this did not work either

Comment: Try with new Date().getTime() first. After it works, then change the way to do it for the correct way, using the firebase Timestamp